# How to upload a firebase function using node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, twilio

i'm going crazy trying to fix this.
first time using firebase, can't seem to be able to create a function.

terminal log:

```
i  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function twilioWebhook(us-central1)...
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    twilioWebhook(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

the firebase debug log shows the same thing.

my goal: trying to have it set up so that it listens for incoming messages on my twilio phone number and adds that phone number to a user database.
here's my index.js file (credentials redacted)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const twilio = require('twilio');

admin.initializeApp();

const client = twilio('redacted', 'redacted');

const usersCollection = 'users';

exports.twilioWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  
  // Check if the message body contains the keyword "join"
  if (body.Body.toLowerCase().includes('join')) {
    const phoneNumber = body.From;
    
    // Add the phone number to the Firestore collection
    const userRef = admin.firestore().collection(usersCollection).doc(phoneNumber);
    await userRef.set({
      phone: phoneNumber,
      joinedAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });
    
    // Send a confirmation message back to the user
    client.messages.create({
      body: 'Thank you for joining!',
      to: phoneNumber,
      from: 'redacted'
    });
  }
  
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

i've tried using node v18, and node v14. whenever i switched node versions i updated my packages.json file to reflect that. still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you follow the indication in the error: "Please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs"

Comment: @RenaudTarnec that did it! my bad for missing the obvious error. was missing twilio dependencies in packages.json
there were two packages.json files, they both needed to contain the twilio dependency